# How to pop immediately to a root view controller after facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, gigya

I need to pop directly to the root view controller after a facebook login.
I can get it to pop to the root view controller.  (for example: [weakSelf.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];)
My issue is that after the facebook login it returns to the original view controller that initiated the facebook login, hangs for a few seconds showing that screen, it then pops the root view controller I need it to go to.  I know the problem is that its leaving the app for the facebook login and then returning to that viewcontroller before popping it.  Any suggestions on what I can do so that the original view controller doesn't show and goes straight to my root VC?

code from ViewController opens facebook login:

```
__weak ForgotPasswordViewController *weakSelf = self;
[ConsumerProfileDataClient facebookLoginWithErrorBlock:^(CPSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [weakSelf.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    } else {
        DebugLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: we need to see your code...how we can understand where is the problem otherwise?

Comment: Give us a example code, for now I can give this answer: You need to make changes to the AppDelegate, by defining a flag or NSNotification when some Facebook Method which you are interested in gets executed and it return you to the viewController you need.

Comment: Checking for it on the AppDelegate makes sense.  Thanks!